# Avoid code smell: Too many hardcode strings or repeating strings across class

Tags: c#, .net

I have a the following code:

```
private const string Item1  = "string1";
private const string Item2  = "string2";
private const string Item3  = "string3";

public Handler()
{
    this.itemType = new Dictionary<string, Func<Guid, string, Task<ManagerDto>>>()
    {
        { Item1, Method1 },
        { Item2, Method2 },
        { Item3, Method2 },
    };

    private async Task<ManagerDto> Method1(Guid ownerId, string ownerType)
    {
        return await actionService.GetItem1(ownerId);
    }

    private async Task<ManagerDto> Method2(Guid ownerId, string ownerType)
    {
        switch (ownerType)
        {
            case Item2:
                return await GetItem2.Get(ownerId);

            case Item3:
                return await GetItem3.Get(ownerId);

            default:
                throw new ArgumentException("Invalid thingy");
        }
    }
}
```

Please note that `Item1` has its own handler, and `Item2` & `Item3` share the same handler.

In the past, the constants `Item1`, `Item2` & `Item3` were just hard coded strings but I refactored it because I was repeating it twice, if one of the strings changed, we would have had to maintain it twice. That's why I introduced those constants.

However, this is being marked by an automatic revision tool as "too many hardcoded values".

Sadly, I cannot use an `enum` with numeric values because `Item1`, `Item2` & `Item3` hold *string* values.

Is there a way that I can avoid declaring `Item1`, `Item2` & `Item3`, and at the same time, avoiding too much hard coded values? I'm very newbie to C# and its pattern. Not sure if I'm being too picky or if I'm really missing something. :)

Comment: What do you mean by -- I cannot use an enum with numeric values because Item1, Item2 & Item3 hold string values. Can you show us what you are trying to do ?

Comment: An enum can only hold numeric values. For example: `Item1 = 1`. In this case `ownerType` is a string, and I cannot change that, so in order to compare, I need `Item1`, `Item2` & `Item3` to be strings. Does it make sense? :D @amitagarwal

Comment: You could store those strings somewhere else like a database or configuration file, then read it from there. If any change is required, you can change that in those files. That would solve the "hardcoded" problem.

Comment: "and I cannot change that" why not?  You can still use an enum internally, allowing you to parse incoming strings to confirm that the value is supported, and convert back to a string if you absolutely have to.

Comment: @gglasses , thats not the purpose of enum. Suggest you to u'stand enum. However in short you can use enum as 
enum Items
    {
        string1,
        string2,
        string3
    }

Comment: Moving a hardcoded (and repeated!) "magic string" like `"string1"` into a well-named (!) constant `Item1` is a good move. You can ignore that warning